# NHibernate Mapping : How to map rows based on a field value

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a `[ContactNumbers]` table as defined below:

```
ID (PK) | PersonID (FK) | NumberType | Number
========|===============|============|=======
```

and a classes defined as:

```
public class Person
{
    ContactNumber homePhone;
    ContactNumber workPhone;
}

public class ContactNumber
{
    string Number;
}
```

How would I define my HBM mapping/s for the `Person` and `ContactNumber` class so that `Person.homePhone` is mapped to the corresponding row in the `[ContactNumbers]` table with the FK observed, and `[ContactNumbers].[NumberType]` equal to `"HOME"`? (`[NumberType]` is `"WORK"` for `Person.workPhone`.)

Already spent a good deal of the day just looking into this, and I couldn't find a solution just yet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map single entity / instance to multiple rows and vice versa.

What you can do is do this:

```
class Person
{
  public IList<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

And then map the ContactNumbers class as a collection / ony-to-many association. The PersonID column is listed as a foriegn key so I assume there is a person table?

Comment: Yup, there is. This is what I thought of first, but was hoping that there was a solution that wouldn't have me knocking on my designer's door to change the code. ;)